Hide/Show forge App Button on JSM portal Request View Action based on request type?
I am new to atlassian development. I have a forge UI kit app with a module on the Jira Service Management portal Request View Action.
How can I restrict the forge app to only be visible on portal Request View Action based on request type?
I’ve tried using displayConditions on the module in the manifest file, but it doesn’t seem to work. Is there documentation on displayConditions as they relate to JSM portal modules? Maybe a list of properties?
If displayConditions doesn’t work on the portal, is there another way to accomplish what I need?
Thanks in advance!
Here is manifest.yml

modules:
  jiraServiceManagement:portalRequestViewAction:
    - key: showhide-hello-world-portal-request-view-action
      resource: main
      resolver:
        function: resolver
      render: native
      title: ShowHide
      icon: https://developer.atlassian.com/platform/forge/images/issue-panel-icon.svg
      displayConditions:
        requestType: Bug
  function:
    - key: resolver
      handler: index.handler

resources:
  - key: main
    path: src/frontend/index.jsx

app:
  runtime:
    name: nodejs20.x
  id: ari:cloud:ecosystem::app/7263b

permissions:
  scopes:
    - read:jira-work
    - read:servicedesk-request
    - manage:jira-configuration
    - read:issue-details:jira
    - read:audit-log:jira
    - read:avatar:jira
    - read:field-configuration:jira
    - read:issue-meta:jira

But displayConditions doesn’t work on the portal, is there another way to accomplish what I need?

From the docs, DisplayConditions can only be used with:

Jira modules
Confluence modules

I had the same problem and unfortunately the only solution I found is to simply check on the initialization of the module is it applicable or not and if not simply show some information to the user.
